# Compare values in two tables and calculate the difference of them

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb-10.3

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d81692c51ad95420ef7182e8f3a477c9)**

```
/* Table Sales */
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    KPI VARCHAR(255),
    sales_volume INT
);

INSERT INTO sales
(product, KPI, sales_volume)
VALUES 
("Product A", "sold", "500"),
("Product A", "sold", "300"),
("Product B", "sold", "200"),
("Product C", "sold", "300"),
("Product D", "sold", "900");


/* Table Logistics */
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    KPI VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(product, KPI, quantity)
VALUES 
("Product A", "outbound", "800"),
("Product B", "outbound", "100"),
("Product B", "outbound", "400"),
("Product C", "outbound", "250"),
("Product D", "outbound", "900");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
product         value_in_sales      value_in_logistics      differnce_of_values
Product A        800                     800                       0
Product B        200                     500                       300
Product C        300                     250                       -50
Product D        900                     900                       0
```

---

In the example above I have two tables called `sales` and `logistics`. 
My target ist to compare the `sales_volume` of the KPI `sold` from the table `sales` with the `quantity` of the KPI `outbound` from the table `logistics`.

I tried to go with `UNION ALL` but it only sorts the values of both tables below each other and does not compare them as in the expected result.

```
SELECT
product,
KPI,
SUM(sales_volume)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
product,
KPI,
SUM(quantity)
FROM logistics
GROUP BY 1
```

What do I need to change in my query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sub-query & do further aggregation :

```
SELECT Product, SUM(logistics),  SUM(Sales),
       SUM(logistics) - SUM(Sales)
FROM (SELECT product, 0 AS logistics, SUM(sales_volume) AS Sales
      FROM sales
      WHERE KPI = 'sold'
      GROUP BY Product
      UNION ALL
      SELECT product, SUM(quantity), 0 
      FROM logistics
      WHERE KPI = 'outbound'
      GROUP BY Product
     ) t
GROUP BY Product;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0b70940653d5bc694cafa4ff1746c90b

Comment: Just for my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=694e4880af61029b8e6a4e4d874467a4

Answer (score 1):

You can do `union all` and then aggregate again:

```
SELECT product, SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(logistics) as logistics,
       (SUM(logistics) - SUM(sales)) as diff
FROM ((SELECT product, SUM(sales_volume) as sales, 0 as logistics
       FROM sales
       WHERE KPI = 'sold'
       GROUP BY product
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT product, 0, SUM(quantity)
       FROM logistics
       WHERE KPI = 'outbound'
       GROUP BY product
      )
     ) p
GROUP BY product;
```

This approach works even if the two tables do not have exactly the same products.